# How to craft an entity in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How can I create the entity `'&#160;'`, if I have the part starting with the '#' in a variable?

When I try to do something like this:

```
concat('&', '#160;')
```

I get an syntax error in XMLspy.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an entity (actually you mean a "character reference"), or will it do just to output a non-breaking space character?

To do the latter, given that `$var` holds `"#160"`, in XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(number(substring($var, 2)))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that, in XML, you cannot use a standalone `&`, so it should be like this:

```
concat('&amp;', '#160;')
```

which outputs `&amp;#160;` if the output method is `xml` and `&#160;` if `text`.

`disable-output-escaping` helps to force `&#160;` in `xml` output:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;', '#160;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Another way to replace a character by an arbitrary string is using character maps:

```
<xsl:output use-character-maps="foo"/>

<xsl:character-map name="foo">
   <xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="&amp;"/>
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;', '#160;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```